# Read files from where the console app shortcut is placed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am creating a console app which reads all files from the folder the exe is placed in. I basically want to place the exe in a folder which has the files, run it, and have it read all the files in that folder.

Unfortunately, I am using a few nuget packages, so I have about 10+ other .dll files, along with appsettings.json file etc. 
I am having to copy all these .dlls along with my .exe file to the folder which contains the files I want to read in order to run it.

1. Is there a way to copy over just the exe file to the folder which contains the files and run it? (I tried this, but my console was closing straight away)
2. Since above didn't work, I was thinking I could create a shortcut of the .exe and just place that in the folder which contains the files. But that seems to be looking for files in the folder which contains the original .exe

Below is my code

```
var folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location);
var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Reading file {filePath}");
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
      records = csvReader.GetRecords<Player>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The executable must be placed where its dependencies are.
2. Executing an executable via a shortcut does not "change" the path where the process is running. The process still lives where the original executable has been launched.

You could consider two workarounds to solve this:

- Copy or move those files on the executable workspace.
- Use absolute paths instead of relative paths based on executable location.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought it might not be possible, but just wanted to check. I will go with absolute path

Comment: @VRoxa the executable can embed its dependencies as resources; that would resolved the issue of the OP

Answer (score 1):

Use cmd file instead of shortcut:

```
pushd %~dp0
Full-Path-to-exe\Program.exe
```